# from @xml.nodes SQL xml

Tags: sql, xml

Wonder if anyone can help. I have an xml string that looks like this.

```
<install>
  <client>
    <account_id><![CDATA[123]]></account_id>
<account_name><![CDATA[123]]></account_name>
<account_name_abbr><![CDATA[123]]></account_name_abbr>
<location>
  <id><![CDATA[5]]></id>
  <name><![CDATA[Bryanston Lab]]></name>
</location>
<ram><![CDATA[10]]></ram>
<cpu><![CDATA[20]]></cpu>
<disk><![CDATA[30]]></disk>
<ip_ranges>
  <item><![CDATA[1.1.1.1/27]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[1.1.1.1/27]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[2.2.2.2/25]]></item>
</ip_ranges>
<vlans>
  <item><![CDATA[4001]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[3000]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[350]]></item>
</vlans>
</client>
</install>
```

I am inserting the data using this

```
insert into tbl_users
select
x.y.value('(account_id)[1]', 'nvarchar(150)') as account_id
,x.y.value('(account_name)[1]', 'nvarchar(350)') as account_name
,x.y.value('(account_name_abbr)[1]', 'nvarchar(150)') as account_name_abbr
,x.y.value('(location/id)[1]', 'int') as location_id
,x.y.value('(cpu)[1]', 'int') as cpu_amount
,x.y.value('(ram)[1]', 'int') as ram_amount
,x.y.value('(disk)[1]', 'int') as disk_amount
from @xml.nodes('//install/client') as x(y)
```

My problem is that Once the initial insert is done I want to insert all the vlans items but i can't figure out how to loop through them and get the correct data.

Please can someone assist me.

Thanks,
Jeb

Comment: once you have inserted into tbl_users, i'm presuming you will get a new UserID auto incremented? and you then want to use this new ID to store with your vlans records in a separate table? if so, we need th details of the other table and the IDs involved to help.

Comment: Yes, correct. The other table is called tbl_user_vlans and the ID is 1

Comment: What are the columns in the new table? What is the ID column name from tbl_users?

Comment: new table columns, id, vlan, user_id. user_id is the foreign key.

Comment: do you want this to cater for more than one Client\tbl_users row at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PK field in tbl_users is auto incremented you can use something like this:

```
insert into tbl_users
select
x.y.value('(account_id)[1]', 'nvarchar(150)') as account_id
,x.y.value('(account_name)[1]', 'nvarchar(350)') as account_name
,x.y.value('(account_name_abbr)[1]', 'nvarchar(150)') as account_name_abbr
,x.y.value('(location/id)[1]', 'int') as location_id
,x.y.value('(cpu)[1]', 'int') as cpu_amount
,x.y.value('(ram)[1]', 'int') as ram_amount
,x.y.value('(disk)[1]', 'int') as disk_amount
from @xml.nodes('//install/client/vlans') as x(y)
declare @tbl_users_id int = scope_identity()

insert tbl_users_vlans([user_id],[vlan])
select @tbl_users_id, x.y.value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(150)')
from @xml.nodes('//install/client/vlans/item') as x(y)
```

You can also do this in transaction if you need.

Comment: This solution assumes a single client is only inserted. If there are multiple clients this will only ever return the last User_Id inserted and hence insert all vlans with the last ID.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That works like a dream. Marked answer as correct :)

Comment: If we have many clients you can use 'output inserted.ID into #t' to get all inseted IDs.